# Angular httpClient - How to get list of images from spring web api

Tags: angular, image, spring-mvc, get, httpclient

I would like to get a list of images from my spring boot web API and display it into my angular front.
For now, I can get a single image and display it into my angular front end.

Below you ll find the backend source code that is working for one image :

```
@GetMapping("/video/getOne/image")
public ResponseEntity<Resource> getFirstVideoImage() throws IOException {
    Path filePath = getFilePath();
    return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG)
            .body(new UrlResource(filePath.toUri()));
}

private Path getFilePath() throws EmailAddressException {
    return Paths.get(DIRECTORY).toAbsolutePath().normalize().resolve(FILE_NAME);
}
```

- 

Below you ll find the front end code that is working for one image :

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.http.get(`${environment.apiUrl}/video/getOne/image`, {
  responseType: "blob"
}).subscribe((response: Blob) => {
  console.log(response);
  this.imageURL = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(URL.createObjectURL(response));
}
);
```

}

---

- 

Below you ll find the back end code I want to achieve (this code does not work):

```
@GetMapping("/video/getall/image")
public ResponseEntity<List<Resource>> getAllImages() throws IOException {
    
    List<Resource> resourceList = new ArrayList<>();
    
    Path filePath1 = getFilePath1();
    resourceList.add(new UrlResource(filePath1.toUri()));
    
    Path filePath2 = getFilePath2();
    resourceList.add(new UrlResource(filePath2.toUri()));
    
    return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG)
            .body(resourceList);
}
private Path getFilePath1() throws EmailAddressException {
    return Paths.get(DIRECTORY).toAbsolutePath().normalize().resolve(FILE_NAME);
}
private Path getFilePath2() throws EmailAddressException {
    return Paths.get(DIRECTORY).toAbsolutePath().normalize().resolve(FILE_NAME);
}
```

- I could not find code sample matching this need.
- Is it possible to do that ?